# composer update on PROD server

Tags: composer-php

There's always been a note in many Readmes of composer-based projects:

> Never run `composer update` on production server

However, there are times that we want to run `composer update` on PROD servers to keep current (of course after a thorough test on local server). What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run on local server.

```
composer update
```

Next you should test application and add `composer.lock` to repository. And on PROD server you should run

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

`composer update` is checking if there are any new versions of the packages available within the limits of the versions given. This will unconditionally install new packages if they are eligible. After that you have to test.

`composer install` will install whatever is mentioned in the lock file, and if the currently installed packages are not the ones mentioned there, they will get uninstalled or updated.

Of course you want to "update" the prod application. But to update the packages, you run `composer install` which will update the packages to the TESTED state in the lock file - not to an UNTESTED state because newer versions did appear after you tested.